# Got "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" in Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, this, prototype

For learning purpose, I wrote a piece of (meaningless) code like this:

```js
Function.prototype.invoke = function(...args) {
    return this(...args);
}
const foo = (a, b) => a + b;
console.log(foo.invoke(1, 2)); // 3, all right!

const arr = [];
arr.push.invoke(1,2); // TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
console.log(arr);
```

Here I define a method on `Function`'s prototype named `invoke`, which is used to just invoke a function by `foo.invoke(args)`(instead of the conventional way `foo(args)`). I wonder why `foo` runs while `arr.push` can't.

As far as I know, this result from the `this` problem. `this` in my `invoke` method is `push`, but `this`'s `this`(`push`'s caller) is `window`, which is not a array-like object(?). But why the error is `Cannot convert undefined or null to object`?

What on earth is the reason for this error? Is there any way to correct it?

Comment: "*"but `push`'s `this` is `window`*" - no, it's not. That's a myth that comes from sloppy-mode functions. The `this` argument is `undefined` when you don't pass a receiver. Try yourself with `(function() { "use strict"; console.log("this value:", this); }).invoke()`

Comment: @Bergi OK, yes, I realize I'm wrong. And `window`, from "has a `length` property" perspective, can be regarded as an array-like object, but still it can't be called using push, though it is another story. Thank you~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr.push` is the same function as `Array.prototype.push`, and `Array.prototype.push` requires a *calling context* to identify which array the argument(s) are going to be pushed to. With

```
arr.push(1, 2);
```

the calling context (what comes before the `.` when the function is invoked) is `arr`. But with your `invoke` there is no calling context:

```
return this(...args);
```

For the same reason, you can't `call` `push` on `undefined`:

```js
Array.prototype.push.call(undefined, 1, 2);
```

If you want to "invoke" a function which requires a calling context, maybe pass the `this` value as the first argument and use `.call`:

```js
Function.prototype.invoke = function(thisVal, ...args) {
    return this.apply(thisVal, args);
}
const foo = (a, b) => a + b;
console.log(foo.invoke(undefined, 1, 2)); // 3, all right!

const arr = [];
arr.push.invoke(arr, 1,2);
console.log(arr);
```

You can also `bind` the `arr.push` to `arr` before calling `invoke`:

```js
Function.prototype.invoke = function(...args) {
    return this(...args);
}
const foo = (a, b) => a + b;
console.log(foo.invoke(1, 2)); // 3, all right!

const arr = [];
arr.push.bind(arr).invoke(1,2);
console.log(arr);
```